# FileSaver does nothing

Tags: javascript, file, filesaver.js

What is wrong with the following code that it does not download/save?

https://jsfiddle.net/36nuqrqm/

```js
function save_file()
{
 var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
 saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js"></script>

aaa
<button id="b" onclick="save_file()">export to CSV</button>
bbb
```

I am using [file saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library

And [here](http://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/) is example of its working code

Comment: Open your dev-tool, you'll see some error pops out that prevents your code to work.

Comment: @fuyushimoya: I am using Firefox under Ubuntu. I observed no error.

Comment: 1. If you click the button on jsfiddle, `Uncaught ReferenceError: save_file is not defined` will pop out, because jsfiddle defaults to use `window.onload` to wrap the script part, you should change its behavior to `nowrap -body/head`.

Comment: 2. I see `Refused to execute script from '.../master/FileSaver.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.` you may have to find some cdn that has the filesaver.js, not from github.

Comment: Hi, I am working on angular application. Everything seems fine. Excel file is being downloaded locally. When I've deployed this code on the server. It does not do anything. Server call successfully executed and return data but file is not being downloaded.
Any one with proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Frameworks & Extensions use No wrap - in  not onLoad for this.

Result using onLoad:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.addEvent('load', function() {
function save_file()
{
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Result using No wrap - in :

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

function save_file()
{
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
}
//]]> 

</script>
```

Or better, using jquery with onLoad
https://jsfiddle.net/36nuqrqm/2/

```
<button id="export_to_csv">export to CSV</button>

$("#export_to_csv").on('click', function (){
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
})
```